# Order of evaluation in ternary operator

Tags: php

I have two snippets of php:

```
function prefix_shortcode_statement_conditional( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<li class="some-class">' . $content == null ? '' : $content . '</li>';
}

function prefix_shortcode_statement( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<li class="some-class">' . $content . '</li>';
}
```

The first snippet has a conditional statement to return an empty string as the `<li>` content, while the second one merely returns the content wrapped in `<li>`.

## prefix_shortcode_statement_conditional output

```
Lorem Ipsum ...
```

## prefix_shortcode_statement output

```
<li class="some-class">
    Lorem Ipsum ... 
</li>
```

As you can see, only the function without the conditional statement properly generates the `<li>` element. Why does one snippet generate the code, but not the other?

---

Wrapping the conditional in parentheses resolves the issue, but fails to help me understand why the issue arose in the first place.

```
return '<li class="some-class">' . ($content == null ? '' : $content) . '</li>';
```

As far as I can tell, php should interpret ending `</li>` as part of the conditional statement, but fails to. Instead of adding `$content . '</li>'` to the output, it instead just returns `$content` and at some level (browser, wordpress, etc), the first `<li>` is removed from the outputted html.

Interestingly, wrapping the `$content` and the `</li>` also fails to display the `<li>...</li>`.

```
return '<li class="mep-testimonial-li">' . $content == null ? '' : ($content . '</li>');
```

I would expect to only see this issue when `$content` is null, so the referenced `</li>` would be omitted and the formatting would shift.

Comment: `return ('<li class="some-class">' . $content == null) ? ('') : ($content . '</li>');` here how your code works.

Comment: *"Does `'<li ...>' . $content` equal `null`, then `''` else `$content . '</li>'`..."*

Comment: `'<li class="some-class">' . $content` does not equal `null`. Try `'<li class="some-class">' . ($content == null ? '' : $content . '</li>')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP, as in other languages, [concatenation have a higher precedence than comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), so:

```
return '<li class="some-class">' . $content == null ? '' : $content . '</li>';
```

Will always print `$content . '</li>'`, since `'<li class="some-class">' . $content` will never be falsy ou null.
This may lead to invalid markup and not be rendered correctly in the browser.

Always wrap your ternaries in parenthesis.

```
return '<li class="some-class">' . ($content == null ? '' : $content) . '</li>';
```

Comment: Why would it print ''? The condition is false, so it will print `$content . '</li>'`

Comment: @maxpovver brings up a valid point, I get the `$content` in the outputted html

Comment: @maxpovver is correct, I misread the code! (answer edited to reflect this)

Answer (score 3):

`'<li class="some-class">' . $content == null ? '' : $content . '</li>';`

This happens becuase for php order here is like this:

`('<li class="some-class">' . $content == null) ? ('') : ($content . '</li>');`

So you always add your content to your ''  string, so it's never null and returns   `$content . '</li>'`

lets make code clearer:

```
$a = '<li class="some-class">' . $content;
$b = '';
$c = $content . '</li>';
return $a == null? $b : $c;
```

As you can see, `$a` is never null so answer is always `$c`